# Change referrer when redirecting

Tags: php

What I'm trying to do is use PHP to redirect from web site A to web site B (both are different domains), but I want the referrer in the HTTP headers to be set to web site A (the page that performed the redirect). So, that is, web site B will see web site A as a referrer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://siteb.net">` on your site A.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty certain that the sending the referrer is ultimately up to the web browser, not PHP. 
You could probably send the address via `$_GET` though.

Edit: You won't be able to change the referrer (misread the post, derp).

Comment: HUH?  Send the address via `$_GET`?  How's that supposed to work?

Comment: I'd suppose something like: `header( "Location: something.php?ref=" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );`

Comment: Ahhhh, that's valid @Kevin, but it's not the referrer header.  But its a valid option depending on requirements

Answer (score 0):

I've checked using localhost and a dummy script. The browser does send the referer in the HTTP even at redirections.

To test this, I created a script called `testRefererRedirect.php`:

```
<?php

if($_GET['a']){

    if($_SERVER['HTTPS'] && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off'){

        echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

    }else{

        header('Location: https://localhost/testrefererredirect.php?a=1');

    }

}else{

    echo '<a href="testrefererredirect.php?a=1">test</a>';

}
```

To emulate cross domains, I used HTTP and HTTPS for my local server.

On first load, the page will show a link: I will click this link to allow the browser to send the referer in the headers. Next, because I load the page initially in HTTP the header function will be called. Finally, the HTTP referer header meant for the 2nd step showed up in the 3rd step.

#### Conclusion

You can safely use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` on website B to capture the refer information meant for website A if you do redirection on website A.